# Copy sub-room placement across channels in Altium

Tags: altium

Consider an Altium project in which I have a channelized block.
Suppose also within that block, I use a sheet symbol to instance another sheet.
An example is shown in Figure 1.

The enclosing room `U_mixer_stage`, (which takes up the whole image) is channelized four times.
Inside that room are two rooms `U_RF_amplifier` and `U_LO_amplifier` coming from sheet symbols that are used in `U_mixer_stage`'s schematic.

I know how to copy the layout of one room to another.
However, how do we also copy the placement of the sub-rooms within the enclosing room, and all of the associated routing?

[image]

I have also asked this on [Altium Live](https://forum.live.altium.com/#posts/220659/640250).

Comment: What happens if you lay out one and then copy the layout of one mixer stage (highest parent) to the others?  Does it barf?

Comment: @JoelWigton no barf. If I do what you suggest, the layout of all of the parts that belong to `mixer_stage`, but *not* the parts that belong to the amplifier sub-blocks, are copied. This appears to be true regardless of the settings chosen in the room-copying dialog.

Comment: I have been trying various strategies involving creation of a "parent room" which contains `mixer_stage`, `LO_amplifier`, and `RF_amplifier`. I think this will eventually work, but so far no dice.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Unless others chime in with a way you can do this, you should probably not try to over-efficientize this, unless you see yourself needing to redo this many times.  You can copy room placement of U_LO and U_RF to all similar (so 6 total copy commands), and then manually place them within the U_mix rooms in the same way (4 manual alignments).  Would be great if there was a way to do what you want, but I don't know of it.  Of course, disregard this if someone knows that it can be done!  Good luck.

Comment: @JoelWigton Ok thanks for the suggestion. It's really disappointing that channelization is so fraught with problems in Altium because it keeps leading me down the garden path and then I have to redo stuff when I hit a missing feature.

Comment: a bit late, but it seems Altium (at the very least AD09) is not able to do this automatically. In case you can read German, see the link below on how to trick the room system into believing the sub room belongs to the main one. This allow to copy room formating including sub rooms, but breaks the schematic update mechanism (cause it only change the PCB). No great, but I do not know of alternatives ...
http://wiki.altium.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=22872356
I didn't heard of any update/improvement of this functionality